# How do I Scrape the link of the website from these page

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape the link from amazon website but they will provide me 2 or 3 links
the link of website is https://www.amazon.com/s?rh=n%3A1069242&fs=true&ref=lp_1069242_sar

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
headers ={
    'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.114 Safari/537.36'
}
r =requests.get('https://www.amazon.com/s?rh=n%3A1069242&fs=true&ref=lp_1069242_sar')
soup=BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
for link in soup.find_all('a',href=True):
        print(link['href'])
```

Comment: Removing selenium cause this is solely asked in beautifulsoup.

Comment: What exactly is the problem here?

Comment: I try to scrape amazon but they give me 2 or 3 links but the  link that I need it will not provide me

Comment: What is "the link you need"? Keep in mind that Beautifulsoup does not run Javascript, and Amazon shopping pages can be dynamically changed.

Comment: this is the link that I need `href="/gp/slredirect/picassoRedirect.html/ref=pa_sp_atf_browse_office-products_sr_pg3_1?ie=UTF8&adId=A05548291XBIAIHL5NQRW&url=%2FSchool-Smart-Ruled-Inches-Sheets%2Fdp%2FB00JKIF350%2Fref%3Dsr_1_49_sspa%3Fdchild%3D1%26qid%3D1633714727%26s%3Doffice-products%26sr%3D1-49-spons%26psc%3D1&qualifier=1633714727&id=2335317438418267&widgetName=sp_atf_browse"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the working solution:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
from urllib.parse import urljoin
base_url='https://www.amazon.com'
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/94.0.4606.71 Safari/537.36','session':'141-2320098-4829807'}
r = requests.get('https://www.amazon.com/s?rh=n%3A1069242&fs=true&ref=lp_1069242_sar', headers = headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')
for link in soup.find_all('a',class_="a-link-normal s-underline-text s-underline-link-text a-text-normal",href=True):
    p=link['href']
    l=urljoin(base_url,p)
    print(l)
```

Output:

```
https://www.amazon.com/gp/slredirect/picassoRedirect.html/ref=pa_sp_atf_browse_office-products_sr_pg1_1?ie=UTF8&adId=A05861132UJ9W79S82Z3&url=%2FFiskars-Inch-Student-Scissors-Pack%2Fdp%2FB08CL355MN%2Fref%3Dsr_1_1_sspa%3Fdchild%3D1%26qid%3D1633717907%26s%3Doffice-products%26sr%3D1-1-spons%26psc%3D1&qualifier=1633717907&id=1565389383398743&widgetName=sp_atf_browse        
https://www.amazon.com/gp/slredirect/picassoRedirect.html/ref=pa_sp_atf_browse_office-products_sr_pg1_1?ie=UTF8&adId=A0918144191FAIKGYK3YC&url=%2FFiskars-Inch-Blunt-Kids-Scissors%2Fdp%2FB00TJSS9ZW%2Fref%3Dsr_1_2_sspa%3Fdchild%3D1%26qid%3D1633717907%26s%3Doffice-products%26sr%3D1-2-spons%26psc%3D1&qualifier=1633717907&id=1565389383398743&widgetName=sp_atf_browse
https://www.amazon.com/gp/slredirect/picassoRedirect.html/ref=pa_sp_atf_browse_office-products_sr_pg1_1?ie=UTF8&adId=A09889161KB2CNO5NB8QC&url=%2FLind-Kitchen-Dispenser-Decorative-Stationery%2Fdp%2FB07VRLW5C6%2Fref%3Dsr_1_3_sspa%3Fdchild%3D1%26qid%3D1633717907%26s%3Doffice-products%26sr%3D1-3-spons%26psc%3D1&qualifier=1633717907&id=1565389383398743&widgetName=sp_atf_browse
https://www.amazon.com/Zebra-Pen-Retractable-Ballpoint-18-Count/dp/B00M382RJO/ref=sr_1_4?dchild=1&qid=1633717907&s=office-products&sr=1-4
```

... so on

Comment: This answer would greatly benefit from a succinct explanation of what’s different about your approach and *why* it works to meet OP’s requirements.

Comment: You need to add cookie and  the url is relative url and  Must make it absolute url . so by using urljoin we can do that easily.